# libxml xmlNodeDump encoding issue

Tags: libxml2, kissxml

I have this code

```
    if(genericPtr->type == XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE){
        xmlAttrPtr attr = (xmlAttrPtr)genericPtr;
        printf("\n str %s\n", (const char *)attr->children->content);
    }

    xmlBufferPtr bufferPtr = xmlBufferCreate();
    if (IsXmlNsPtr(genericPtr)){
        xmlNodeDump(bufferPtr, NULL, (xmlNodePtr)genericPtr, 0, format);
    }else{
        xmlNodeDump(bufferPtr, ((xmlStdPtr)genericPtr)->doc, (xmlNodePtr)genericPtr, 0, format);
    }

    printf("\n str2 %s\n", (const char *)bufferPtr->content);
```

The result is

```
str чатрум@muc.chat.quickblox.com/300

str2  to="&#x447;&#x430;&#x442;&#x440;&#x443;&#x43C;@muc.chat.quickblox.com/300"
```

In result i need **чатрум** instead

```
&#x447;&#x430;&#x442;&#x440;&#x443;&#x43C;
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`xmlNodeDumpOutput`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDumpOutput) which allows you to specify an encoding. Note that it uses an `xmlOutputBuffer` instead of an `xmlBuffer`. Another useful function is [`xmlXPathCastNodeToString`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathCastNodeToString) which returns the XPath string value of a node as `xmlChar`.

Comment: Hi, I'm using exactly this method, the xmlNodeDumpOutput but even declaring the required output encoding I have always an UTF-8 output.
Can you point me the right direction?

Comment: @Mr.Gate What encoding are you trying to use? Are you sure it's supported by your libxml2 installation?